# Best way to storage positions after click in button inside Recycler View

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, retrofit2

I have Recycler View like in this picture.
After click to button (B in picture) i want to get position id and storage this positions in best possible way to access and list data in other activity. After all I want to send all positions in ArrayList (for example) by Retrofit to backend.

Any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- First make one callback listener like   **btnClickedListener**
- Set it through RecyclerView Adapter and implement it to the **activity** with position parameter
- Then make an array list of positions in the activity and send it to the next activity by using **Gson** or **String**

Answer (score 1):

This is code from my working project hope will help you.

```
// all item click listener
private RowItemElementClickListener mListener;

public RowViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    // constructor

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            if (getListener() != null) {
                getListener().onLayoutClick(view, RowViewHolder.this.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Interface**

```
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Wasim on 17/06/16.
 */
public interface RowItemElementClickListener {

    void onLayoutClick(View v, int position);
    boolean onLayoutLongClick(View v, int position);

}
```

Use this interface with recycler view to pass any object click event to activity or fragment. implement interface in that and you have full control over click and long click.